# Swift Xcode How to toggle colour of a shape with each tap of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I thought something like this would work but feel like my function is improper. It compiles but doesn't do anything and I'm not even sure it can work like this. I am very new to swift and appreciate any help.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        _ = touch.locationInNode(self)

        colorSwitch()
               }
}

func colorSwitch(){

    if (ShapeY.color == UIColor.whiteColor()) {
        ShapeY.color = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    else if (ShapeY.color == UIColor.blackColor()) {
        ShapeY.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a circle. I have a circle in the middle of the screen and I want to change its colour from black to white to black when I tap. I should have been more clear.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice this comment until now. It was a sprite node. I had another idea of setting the colourBlendFactor to equal a variable CGFloat called colourTT initialised to 1. I then wanted to set it so that this was multiplied by -1 whenever there was a touch to make it switch between black and white and came up with    

`override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        colourTT *= -1
      
        
    } ` This doesn't work at all for me though.

Comment: I got rid of the extra variable colourTT and just did this but it seems to stop after one touch. How can I make it see other touches?

`override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        
        Mainball.colorBlendFactor *= -1.0
        
    }`

Comment: I solved it by using and would love to know why the others didn't work and what made this one work instead in case anyone sees this post.

`override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {       
 
        if Mainball.colorBlendFactor == 1.0 {
            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
                
                Mainball.colorBlendFactor = -1.0
            }
            
        } else if Mainball.colorBlendFactor != 1.0 {
            Mainball.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        }
    }
`

Answer (score -1):

Colors cannot be compared using the `==` operator, so both if statements evaluate to false. Try changing `==` to:

```
ShapeY.color.isEqual(UIColor.whiteColor())
```

You may have to use `!` to unwrap the optional:

```
ShapeY.color!.isEqual(UIColor.whiteColor())
```

Comment: I get an error when I put in a ! and nothing happens now that I've changed == to isEqual but at least I have something to work with. If I figure out the if statements should it work? Will my function colourSwitch get called each time there's a tap or will it just get called once?